# i am not able to submit this code in hackerank python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, error-handling, compiler-errors

# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
N=int(input())
M=int(input())

b="welcome"

for i in range(1,N+1):

```
if i<(N+1)/2:
    s = ".|." * (2 * i - 1)
    print(s.center(M,'-'))
    k=2*i-1
if i==(N+1)/2:
    print(b.center(M,'-'))
if i>((N+1)/2):
    l=".|."*k
    print(l.center(M,'-'))
    k=k-2
```

this code is running properly in pycham but hackerrank says compile time erro

Answer (score 0):

Try using `elif` for the second and `else` for third condition (in which case it does not need a condition). Normally you would write a control flow for a variable as

```
if:

elif:

elif:

...

else:
```

EDIT: Also make sure that the platform where you submit your code sees your indentation as 4 spaces.